# C# Swagger Custom in Nuget Package

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-ui, .net-7.0

I'm creating a nuget package to customize Swagger... The goal is not to have to configure it all the time, copying and pasting the configurations and .css and .js files from other projects.

Thus, placing in the AppSettings only the variables that you want to change, such as version, title, description, contacts and security if you have one.

My problem is this snippet:

```
public static void UseSwagger(this WebApplication? app)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(opt =>
    {
        opt.DocumentTitle = app.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Swagger:DocumentTitle") ?? "Custom Title Swagger";
        opt.InjectStylesheet("/swagger-ui/custom.css");
        opt.InjectJavascript("/swagger-ui/custom.js");
    });
}
```

In my package, it imports the .css and .js, however, when I use the package in any application, it cannot import the files, getting the default Swagger style.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Did you setup your .csproj file to copy the .css and .js files to the output directory? Something like this:
`<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="*.css">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <Pack>true</Pack>
      <PackagePath>build\</PackagePath>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>`

Comment: More info on Common MSBuild targets can be found in the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items?view=vs-2019#none)